# .htaccess allow images in one subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website and .htaccess file that disable the access to all images and pdf file.
I added a new sub-folder and I need to allow the outside access to the images and PDFs in this sub folder.
How do I do it?

```
RewriteEngine on
AuthName "myname"
AuthUserFile "/home/virtual/website/.htpasswds/public_html/mywebsite/passwd"
<files ~ "^(admin(.*)\.(php|js))$">
require valid-user 
</files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|pdf)$ - [F,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add another `RewriteCond` to check for sub-folder:

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI) !^/sub-folder/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|png|bmp|pdf)$ - [F,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add a condition to exclude the sub folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://website.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|pdf)$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: Both answers posted at exact same second :) but this will unblock `/subfolder123.pdf` file

Comment: Thanks!! @anubhava - It's OK, I don't have a file with this name :)